# If I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Ubuntu 20.04 will grub know how to handle it?

Tags: grub2

I have a disk with a Ubuntu 20.04 partition and a 18.04 partition.
If I update the 18.04 one to 20.04 I will have problems in grub?

Comment: You may want to edit grub condition so that you can tell the difference between the two, but grub **should not** have any problems.

Comment: Yep, I've had as many as 5x same releases on a *testing* box (where I was QA-testing *flavors* of 18.04.3 for example; I didn't do that in later cycles).  As noted in earlier comments; they can be hard to tell apart in `grub` by the user (ie. you the user may find differentiating one from the other) but `grub` will handle it without issue.

Comment: By default the only unique distinction that grub will display is the partition.  During install (or after) take note of which partition contains which installation.  Example: Xubuntu on sda4, Kubuntu on sda6.  Or edit the grub accordingly as @user6818 suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, grub is smart enought, so when you are booting, you will see a list of all Operating Systems available, and yes, if you have multiples versions installed from the same 20.04, grub will show in wich partition which one is installed